# Fabricjs: Background Image not rendering on undo

Tags: javascript, angularjs, canvas, fabricjs

I am implementing undo feature in my canvas and I am stuck on the background image property. I am using this to save the current state of canvas

```
var myjson = JSON.stringify(canvas);
$rootScope.state.push(myjson);
$rootScope.mods++;
```

On undo, I am getting this state and loading using this code:

```
$rootScope.undo = function () {
    canvas.clear().renderAll();
    canvas.loadFromJSON($rootScope.state[$rootScope.mods - 1], function(){
        canvas.renderAll();
    });
}
```

Everything is working fine except background image do not render at all. Please help.

This is the JSON string of the canvas state if anyone wants to take a look.

```
"{\"objects\":[{\"type\":\"i-text\",\"originX\":\"left\",\"originY\":\"top\",\"left\":25,\"top\":25,\"width\":182,\"height\":41.95,\"fill\":\"#000\",\"stroke\":null,\"strokeWidth\":1,\"strokeDashArray\":null,\"strokeLineCap\":\"butt\",\"strokeLineJoin\":\"miter\",\"strokeMiterLimit\":10,\"scaleX\":1,\"scaleY\":1,\"angle\":0,\"flipX\":false,\"flipY\":false,\"opacity\":1,\"shadow\":null,\"visible\":true,\"clipTo\":null,\"backgroundColor\":\"\",\"fillRule\":\"nonzero\",\"globalCompositeOperation\":\"source-over\",\"text\":\"Heading text\",\"fontSize\":32,\"fontWeight\":800,\"fontFamily\":\"Roboto\",\"fontStyle\":\"\",\"lineHeight\":1.16,\"textDecoration\":\"\",\"textAlign\":\"center\",\"textBackgroundColor\":\"\",\"styles\":{}}],\"background\":\"\",\"backgroundImage\":{\"type\":\"rect\",\"originX\":\"left\",\"originY\":\"top\",\"left\":0,\"top\":0,\"width\":250,\"height\":250,\"fill\":{\"type\":\"linear\",\"coords\":{\"x1\":0,\"y1\":0,\"x2\":125,\"y2\":125},\"colorStops\":[{\"offset\":\"0\",\"color\":\"rgb(210,77,87)\",\"opacity\":1},{\"offset\":\"1\",\"color\":\"rgb(249,191,59)\",\"opacity\":1},{\"offset\":\"0.5\",\"color\":\"rgb(31,58,147)\",\"opacity\":1}],\"offsetX\":0,\"offsetY\":0},\"stroke\":null,\"strokeWidth\":1,\"strokeDashArray\":null,\"strokeLineCap\":\"butt\",\"strokeLineJoin\":\"miter\",\"strokeMiterLimit\":10,\"scaleX\":1,\"scaleY\":1,\"angle\":0,\"flipX\":false,\"flipY\":false,\"opacity\":1,\"shadow\":null,\"visible\":true,\"clipTo\":null,\"backgroundColor\":\"\",\"fillRule\":\"nonzero\",\"globalCompositeOperation\":\"source-over\",\"rx\":0,\"ry\":0}}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse the stringified json.

***DEMO***

```js
var jsonS = "{\"objects\":[{\"type\":\"i-text\",\"originX\":\"left\",\"originY\":\"top\",\"left\":25,\"top\":25,\"width\":182,\"height\":41.95,\"fill\":\"#000\",\"stroke\":null,\"strokeWidth\":1,\"strokeDashArray\":null,\"strokeLineCap\":\"butt\",\"strokeLineJoin\":\"miter\",\"strokeMiterLimit\":10,\"scaleX\":1,\"scaleY\":1,\"angle\":0,\"flipX\":false,\"flipY\":false,\"opacity\":1,\"shadow\":null,\"visible\":true,\"clipTo\":null,\"backgroundColor\":\"\",\"fillRule\":\"nonzero\",\"globalCompositeOperation\":\"source-over\",\"text\":\"Heading text\",\"fontSize\":32,\"fontWeight\":800,\"fontFamily\":\"Roboto\",\"fontStyle\":\"\",\"lineHeight\":1.16,\"textDecoration\":\"\",\"textAlign\":\"center\",\"textBackgroundColor\":\"\",\"styles\":{}}],\"background\":\"\",\"backgroundImage\":{\"type\":\"rect\",\"originX\":\"left\",\"originY\":\"top\",\"left\":0,\"top\":0,\"width\":250,\"height\":250,\"fill\":{\"type\":\"linear\",\"coords\":{\"x1\":0,\"y1\":0,\"x2\":125,\"y2\":125},\"colorStops\":[{\"offset\":\"0\",\"color\":\"rgb(210,77,87)\",\"opacity\":1},{\"offset\":\"1\",\"color\":\"rgb(249,191,59)\",\"opacity\":1},{\"offset\":\"0.5\",\"color\":\"rgb(31,58,147)\",\"opacity\":1}],\"offsetX\":0,\"offsetY\":0},\"stroke\":null,\"strokeWidth\":1,\"strokeDashArray\":null,\"strokeLineCap\":\"butt\",\"strokeLineJoin\":\"miter\",\"strokeMiterLimit\":10,\"scaleX\":1,\"scaleY\":1,\"angle\":0,\"flipX\":false,\"flipY\":false,\"opacity\":1,\"shadow\":null,\"visible\":true,\"clipTo\":null,\"backgroundColor\":\"\",\"fillRule\":\"nonzero\",\"globalCompositeOperation\":\"source-over\",\"rx\":0,\"ry\":0}}";

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
canvas.loadFromJSON(JSON.parse(jsonS),function(){
 canvas.renderAll();
})
```

```css
canvas{
 border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id='c' width=250 height=250></canvas>
```

To serialize canvas use [canvas.toJSON()](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#toJSON)
`var myjson = canvas.toJSON();`